# 32 bit packages Job Activity Monitor

Tags: sql-server, ssms, jobs, 32-bit

How do i go about finding all the packages within the Job Activity Monitor that runs off a 32 bit, or would i have to search through each package individually.

Thanks Much Appreciated

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: i am using MS SQL Server